# How to define a custom exception in Haskell?

Tags: exception, haskell

The Control.Exception documentation says I can do the following to create my own exception:

```
 data MyException = ThisException | ThatException
     deriving (Show, Typeable)

 instance Exception MyException
```

If I paste this into a file and compile (after importing Control.Exception and Data.Typeable), I get:

```
exp.hs:6:20:
    Can't make a derived instance of `Typeable MyException'
      (You need -XDeriveDataTypeable to derive an instance for this class)
    In the data type declaration for `MyException'
```

Must I turn on this extension in order to have user-defined exceptions? If not, someone please provide an example. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you need to turn on that extension. It's not a good idea to try to write the `Typeable` instance by hand because it has some ties to the internals of GHC.

Comment: Does this mean that in general, no user-defined exceptions in Haskell?

Comment: If you mean the Haskell standard, then there are no user-defined exceptions. If you mean the extended language implemented by GHC, then they do exist, as above.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can easily define `Exception`, and use it.

```hs
module Main (main) where
import Control.Exception
import GHC.IO (catchException)
data DropException = DropException deriving (Show)
instance Exception DropException
go = throwIO DropException
main = catchException go (\DropException -> putStrLn "Dropped")
```